# Set an event listener onto a bootstrap popover element

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

Is there a way to get the actual popover element, in order to set an event listener onto the popover?

For example

```
 jq("#theElement").popover.on('click', function(){console.log("hello world")});
```

Comment: Perhaps this will be of some help to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205103/attach-event-handler-to-button-in-twitter-bootstrap-popover - It uses event delegation to attach an event to the popover's parent, which is triggered by a button inside the popover.

Comment: @Santi Unfortunately i'm required to set `container:'body'` which results in the `.parent()` element not actually being a parent of the `popover` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the popover element with `jq(e.element).data('bs.popover').tip()`

```
jq(e.element).data('bs.popover').tip().on("click",function(){ 
      console.log("hello world");
});
```